# Move rows containing a word from a list to a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to:

1. create a new sheet called "results" after the first sheet (to the right)
2. on the original sheet search Column B for if any of an array of words is present in a cell
3. if found select the row and move it to the sheet called results
4. delete the empty space from the moved row

An example would be to search the column for any cell that had "casual" and one cell had "Casual Worker".
I want the macro to select that row and cut and paste it to the results sheet, then go back and delete the empty cell.

I think an array for the words would work best as the list of words might change.

The sheet always has the info in the same column so its always column b that has the words.

I am able to code the macro if Column b only contained the word but 99% of the time it's part of a string of text.

I found code to create a new sheet after the original and then name it something. Then I found how to select words from B and make it select the row and move it to the other sheet.

Its mainly setting up the array and then searching for specific words in a line of text in each cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [InStr()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) to search for a string within a longer string. Then I would just loop through a range in your workbook for a list of the words you want to search for. I would probably use a macro something like the following based on your description of what you want.

```
Private Sub SearchAndMove()
    
    Dim SearchSheetName As String
    Dim NewSheetName As String
    Dim SearchRng As Range
    Dim SearchWords() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As Range
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Name of original sheet that will be searched
    SearchSheetName = "Search"
    'Name of new sheet for search results
    NewSheetName = "Results"
    
    'Add new sheet if it doesn't already exist
    If Not SheetExists(NewSheetName) Then
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(SearchSheetName)
        ActiveSheet.Name = NewSheetName
        Range("A1") = "Results"
    End If
    
    Sheets(SearchSheetName).Activate
    Set SearchRng = Range(Range("B1"), Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Cells
    SearchWords = Array("Word1", "Word2", "Word3")
    
    'Loop through each cell and move to new tab where there is a match to our lookup words
    For i = 0 To UBound(SearchWords)
        For Each c In SearchRng
            If InStr(1, c.Value2, SearchWords(i), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then 'Use vbBinaryCompare if you want the comparison to be case sensitive
                Sheets(NewSheetName).Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = c.Value2
                c.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            End If
        Next c
    Next i
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

'Function to check if a sheet exists
'Returns TRUE if the sheet exists in the active workbook
Function SheetExists(SheetName As String) As Boolean
    SheetExists = False
    On Error GoTo NoSuchSheet
    If Len(Sheets(SheetName).Name) > 0 Then
        SheetExists = True
        Exit Function
    End If
NoSuchSheet:
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Really appreciate that. Only question i have is where exactly to put the search words. I see the 'searchwords' range but not sure where exactly where to add the words. Or how to format them in a list. Should the list of words just have spaces between or commas or underscores. Sorry if your notes already mention this

Comment: Sorry actually i see the code setting the words. Just still not 100% on how to write in. With spaces ect

Comment: I added a column to the workbook for the list of the words I wanted to search for, one word in each cell. I named that range "SearchWords" to make it easier to reference and then looped through the range to check each word.

Comment: Can this range of words be in either sheet ? Or fors the code just look for the title searchwords

Comment: And would there be a way to just define them in the code, rather than on the sheet. If not i will just make a macro to write the words automatically to save spelling errors

Comment: You can define an array within the code if that is what you'd prefer.  I edited my original answer to do it this way.